# Fetch UTF-8 Characters from a different language Website

Tags: java, jar, web-scraping

I am trying to fetch data from a website which is in Hungarian language. This site also has some UTF-8 characters i.e. ő. So when i scrap the data from website, it changes special characters into some unknown characters. I need to get the data in same hungarian language.
Right now i am using gargoylesoftware.htmlunit jar file to scrap the data.
Please tell me how can i achieve this by using any specific method or do i need some other jar files?
Here's a piece of code i am using.

```
 HtmlElement doctorInstitutionTitlePhone =  page.getFirstByXPath(".//*[@id='orvosok_kartyajinak_helye']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div[3]");
 String sDITP = doctorInstitutionTitlePhone.asText();
```

Comment: There's no such thing a a "UTF-8 character" - there *is* a Unicode character encoded in UTF-8, but it's possible that this web site is using a different encoding. Do you know what encoding it *is* using?

Comment: Could you show the code you're using to get the content? There are multiple methods, some do the character set "decoding" for you automatically, some don't.

Comment: Are you sure the site is actually sending data encoded using UTF-8? What does the `Content-Type` header say?

Comment: @JonSkeet how can i know what encoding is this site using? if you want i can give you the url of site.

Comment: @fge I didn't understand it properly, but still i think you are asking about it.  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">

Comment: What type is `page`? HtmlPage?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yes its a html page.

Comment: No, I am talking about the `Content-Type` HTTP header

Comment: Sorry, then I can't see anything wrong in the code you're showing, asText on a `HtmlDivision` should get the visual representation using the current page encoding (which should be UTF-8, although you can verify using [getPageEncoding()](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html#getPageEncoding())